# What are default permissions or configuration? Revert chmod 777

Tags: permissions, chmod

I am new to Ubuntu and Linux, and appear to have made a mistake. I was currently logged in as root and was encountering a permission issue in my python file where I could not create a file when using the following.

```
open('test.txt', 'w')
```

To resolve this, I ran the following.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 ~/MyDir
```

Everything became highlighted in light green, indicating that it is executable. Upon further reading, I understood that this is actually a significant mistake.

I've been fumbling around with various chmod commands, but it seems to be getting worse. Just to make sure that I'm not breaking anything or my program doesn't encounter issues due to my inexperience, how can I reconfigure my directory and files to go back to normal from `chmod -R 777 ~/MyDir` to normal files and folders, where I can write with `open("text.txt", 'w')`?

Comment: 644 are decent permissions for non executable files. the numbers are for owner, group and lastly all others. the permissions are read=4 write=2 execute=1. if you add the desired permissions you get the number to use. in this case 6=read+write for owner and 4=read for group and all other

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the default permissions of directories in home (Desktop, Downloads, etc.)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/604489/what-are-the-default-permissions-of-directories-in-home-desktop-downloads-etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nearest you will probably get to "default" permissions are those implied by your login session or shell's `umask` value ex. if `umask` returns `0002` then the default octal permissions are `0664` for files and `0775` for directories; while if `umask` is `0022` they are respectively `0644` and `0755`.

You can *apply* such permissions using

```
find ~/MyDir -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} +

find ~/MyDir -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} +
```

Obviously you will need to manually correct cases such as executable scripts or program files that will need their executable bit set to run properly.

Comment: Ubuntu Home directories were created with 755 permissions but will be dropped to 750 with 21.04,  now to prevent new home directories from being readable by other users on the system.

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked perfectly!